# System gradually freezes on USB device resetting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, usb, freeze

I'm using a serial terminal to interact with a micro-controller (bluepill-STM32F103-genuine) over USB ACM. It works fine upon powering up. But upon resetting the board, it hangs my system in a way that I only can reboot with SysReq sequences.
(I've fixed the wrong resistors on USB pins of bluepill).

The hang is gradual. First fans start spinning, then temp goes up, then WiFi turns off, then complete freeze of the OS.
Strange thing is CPU usage becomes 100% but no process is using that much cpu!
Here is journalctl at the moment of resetting: 16:26

```
Nov 04 16:19:47 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 6 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:20:00 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:20:00 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:20:02 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:20:02 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:21:40 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:21:40 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:21:40 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:21:40 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:21:40 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Successfully made thread 8675 of process 8588 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Nov 04 16:21:40 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 6 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:21:51 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 6 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:21:51 thinkpad rtkit-daemon[2845]: Supervising 6 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Nov 04 16:25:01 thinkpad CRON[9155]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 04 16:25:01 thinkpad CRON[9156]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov 04 16:25:01 thinkpad CRON[9155]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-hwe-5.4-P3jn7z/linux-hwe-5.4-5.4.0/kernel/workqueue.c:1477 __queue_work+0x35f/0x400
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: Modules linked in: cdc_acm ccm aufs overlay vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc v
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc rtsx_pci psmouse ahci e1000e libahci wmi video
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G           OE     5.4.0-52-generic #57~18.04.1-Ubuntu
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 20BXCT01WW/20BXCT01WW, BIOS JBET73WW (1.37 ) 08/14/2019
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: RIP: 0010:__queue_work+0x35f/0x400
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: Code: 25 c0 6b 01 00 f6 47 24 20 74 18 e8 9b 92 00 00 48 85 c0 74 0e 48 8b 40 20 48 3b 58 08 0f 84 d7 fc ff ff 0f 0b e9 f7 fd ff ff <0f> 0b 
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb4c3c0003c40 EFLAGS: 00010002
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: RAX: ffff9be6273dd790 RBX: ffff9be6a480ce00 RCX: 0000000000000000
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: RDX: ffff9be6273dd798 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff9be6a5a2a680
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: RBP: ffffb4c3c0003c78 R08: ffff9be6a4400920 R09: ffff9be6a4400948
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffffa425d958 R12: 0000000000000000
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: R13: 0000000000002000 R14: ffff9be6273dd790 R15: ffff9be6a5a2f700
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9be6a5a00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: CR2: 00007f6727af3000 CR3: 00000001e4c0a006 CR4: 00000000003606f0
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel: Call Trace:
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  <IRQ>
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  queue_work_on+0x39/0x40
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  acm_write_bulk+0x70/0x80 [cdc_acm]
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  __usb_hcd_giveback_urb+0x93/0x120
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  usb_hcd_giveback_urb+0xb8/0xe0
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  xhci_giveback_urb_in_irq.isra.46+0x84/0xf0
Nov 04 16:26:06 thinkpad kernel:  xhci_td_cleanup+0xe2/0x180
```

Xubuntu 18.04
5.4.0-52-generic